# How to know if a decimal number is 0x1000 or 0x0100

Tags: android, bitmask

I have set of data, with a column value named Type, I need to know if the value is 0x1000 or 0x0010 or 0x0200, I don't have any idea, can you please help

Comment: Compare it? Use a bitwise AND (`&&`)? What's the actual issue?!

Comment: bitwise is  single & ... but still where is the problem?

Comment: How can I know if this decimal number 21568 is 0x1000 or 0x0010 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programming in Android will accept a few alternate ways of storing integer numbers.

```
int mask = 0x1000;
```

is valid. you can then compare it just like a normal int

```
if (type == mask)
//do something
```

you can also perform bitwise operations with integers. Most relevant here is probably bitwise and(&)if you're using a mask. Since you called it a mask, I'm going to assume you know how bitwise operations work and just show you how to invoke them. If you don't know, please leave a comment and I'll update it.

```
int result = type & mask; //where both type and mask are ints
if(result == 0){
//type did not match mask
}
else if(result == type){
//all bits in the mask were present in type
}
else{
//some bits in type matched the mask
}
```

that should get you to where you want to go I think.

Happy coding! Leave a comment if you have any questions.

Comment: I don't know how bitwise operations work, can you please explain , thank you so much